# EPPlus Excel File Fill.PatternType, Fill.PatternColor or Fill.BackgroundColor

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm trying to generate an Excel file that has a background like a normal excel file. When I create mine in my program it sets the background to black and you can't see anything. I am not sure if I am setting wrong properties but here's what I am trying:

```
sheet.Cells.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
//sheet.Cells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor( Color.Empty );
sheet.Cells.Style.Fill.PatternColor.SetColor( Color.Transparent );
```

All I am trying to do is create an excel file that has no background like the way it would look you create a blank excel file manually. Any ideas?[image: See This Image as an example]

Comment: What if you simply omitted both line?  You shouldnt really have to touch the background Styling if you just want to go with defaults.

Comment: Hi @Ernie, I would like to set a background-color for a cell somewhere in the worksheet and it forces me to set `Fill.PattenType`

Comment: @Ernie, I resolved this by only setting the `Fill.PatternType` for the concerned cell.

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you have to do is:

```
ws.Cells[range].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.None;
//ws.Cells[range].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);
```

in your own code:

```
sheet.Cells.Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.None;
//sheet.Cells.Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor( Color.Empty );
//sheet.Cells.Style.Fill.PatternColor.SetColor( Color.Transparent );
```

That's it

Answer (score 0):

ws.Cells[range].Style.Fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.None;
ws.Cells[range].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(System.Drawing.Color.Transparent);

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**